# Things to mention on the resume for a fresher

Tags: resume, tech-industry, fresher

Most of the resume tips i have seen on the internet dedicate a big fat portion to **Experience**. Since i am a fresher i have little to none experience (No internships either). I have a few Web Development group projects (that included front end + back end) that i have developed during college and a few front end projects i have developed for my online course at Free Code Camp like this [one](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/use-the-twitchtv-json-api). I am applying for a position of front end engineer preferably at startups. So my questions are:

- What all things do i mention in my resume?
- How to describe my projects so that i convey the skills gained from them but also have something (or a lot) to talk about in an actual interview?
- Since i am applying for a front end engineer, would designing a resume with web front end technologies make me stand out a bit or would it too much?

Answer (score 4):

Mention anything which demonstrates shills that will be useful to the prospective employers.

Describe what you did in the résumé; discuss why you did it that way and how you overcame challenges in the interview.

Résumé should be plaintext. If you want a portfolio showing what you can do, that is a separate item.

Comment: I am thinking about making a resume with HTML/CSS with a simplictic design(rough outline: http://codepen.io/binarytrance/pen/xOoydX ) and converting it into PDF. I mean, if you are a startup and are hiring front end web engineers, wouldn't you appreciate the effort and... doing it differently than most?

Comment: @snow - no. We'd rather you have a simple text-based resume format and links to a portfolio or project sites - besides, if you're distributing it as PDF we won't see the front end web engineering, just graphic design...

Comment: @HorusKol and here i spent a full day coming up with the design, learning about flexboxes and coding it in :( anyway could you point me to a couple of good examples for a resume (preferably for a fresher)? Thanks.

Comment: @snow - flexboxes are cool - come up a with portfolio site that uses them... I don't have examples of resumes to point to - but there are plenty of questions on this site about what to include and how to lay out a fresher's resume.

Comment: Pointers to resources are generally off topic here, but a simple web search or a trip to the library or a question to your school's guidance/placement office should find lots of examples.

Comment: @HorusKol in every project i had used bootstrap and it made things so much easier. However i decided to go bare hands into this one and realized css can be as hard as catching a squirrel. I lost a lot of hair over floats and realized they suck. Finding about flexboxes was like striking gold. Anyways, thank you and keshlam